Is Google Maps timeline now less detailed?
Since a few days ago (coinciding roughly with the migration of Maps Timeline to be "on device") the tracks recorded by timeline are no longer accurate or useful. Where before tracks used to be no different from the sort of thing one might see in a workout or cycling app, they are now just a bunch of random zigzags roughly constrained to the paces visited.
Are other users experiencing the same degradation in timelines data, or is there perhaps something I can do to improve the quality I'm getting as Google migrates some of timelines functionality from the cloud to devices?

Location History is now Timeline, a mobile-only app. Users are receiving notifications to move their data to their phones. After that, Location History will no longer be available in the web app. Users who fail to migrate their data to mobile by the deadlines in their email and/or device notifications, may lose their visit and route history according to Google.
Questions about the app are on-topic on [apple.se] or [android.se].

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
